# Can't passing parameter to the loop

Tags: javascript, loops, scope

I want to alert different word base on different actions, but it doesn't work.

this is my code:

```
<input id=main value="ddddd">
 <script type="text/javascript">
var obj = document.getElementById("main");
var items = [ "click", "keypress" ];
for ( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++ ) {
        obj[ "on" + items[i] ] = function() {
            alert( "Thanks for your " + items[i] );
        };
}
 </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a closure. Something like that should work:

```
function makeClosure(eventName) {
    return function() {
        alert( "Thanks for your " + eventName );
    };
}

var obj = document.getElementById("main");
var items = [ "click", "keypress" ];
for ( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++ ) {
        obj[ "on" + items[i]] = makeClosure(items[i]);
}​
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NQKqk/